# Who treated Hitler when he was wounded in World War 1?

Tags: hitler, medicine

Hitler was [wounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_career_of_Adolf_Hitler#First_World_War) in World War 1 (October 1916) and was treated for two months at a hospital in Brandenburg.

Is it recorded which doctor(s) treated Hitler during this period? If yes, did he/she say anything about how, by conforming to the Hippocratic Oath, he/she indirectly caused World War 2 and millions of death?

I can't find anything on Google about this. The closest is [this source](https://www.scielo.br/j/anp/a/wD3DjhK4jmZNz4Yk866ThqL/?lang=en), which names Dr. Karl Kroner and Dr. Edmund Robert Forster as Hitler's doctors for a bout of hysterical blindness he suffered in 1917. However, the blindness was a mental illness, not a physical wound.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132719/discussion-on-question-by-allure-who-treated-hitler-when-he-was-wounded-in-world).

Comment: Your mention of "how, by conforming to the Hippocratic Oath, he/she indirectly caused World War 2 and millions of death" seems a bit out of scope and more a polemic statement.